# Build Failure with Nextpeer

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, nextpeer

I'm new with Unity and plugin integration.

I followed the Nextpeer Unity tutorial step by step and I now have a problem when trying to run my game on my Nexus 5.

I get this error when I try to build my project :

```
Error building Player: Win32Exception: ApplicationName='C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin\javac.exe', CommandLine='-bootclasspath "C:/AndroidDevTools/sdk/platforms/android-19\android.jar" -d "MYGAMEPATH\Temp\StagingArea\bin\classes" -source 1.6 -target 1.6 -encoding ascii "MYGAMEBUNDLEID\R.java" "com\nextpeer\android\R.java"', CurrentDirectory='MYGAMEPATH\Temp\StagingArea\gen'
```

It was working just fine before I integrated the Nextpeer plugin.

I'm using Unity v4.3.4f1 and the Nextpeer Unity SDK v2.2.15

Maybe you can help, thanks.

Comment: Please use unity3d tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case people have the same issue, I finally fixed it... For some reasons, since I imported this plugin the build requires a Java 32bits while I've been using a 64bits version this whole time.
So installing a 32bits JDK solved my issue.